# awk problems remembering previous line

Tags: awk

I have the following awk file;

```
BEGIN { FS=":" };
{if (NR%2==1) { host=$1 }};
{if (NR%2==0) { print $host ":" $0 }};
```

I want to do the following;

If the line # is odd, store the 1st field.

If the line # is even, print the previously stored field, a colon, plus the current line.

currently this outputs the even numbered line twice "evenline:evenline"

not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
BEGIN { FS=":" };
{if (NR%2==1) { host=$1 }};
{if (NR%2==0) { print host ":" $0 }};
```

`$host` -> `host`.

---

Why?

Field names in `awk` start with a dollar `$` in front. You can access fields in `awk` statically like `$1`, `$2` etc. or dynamically like `$variable`. Variables will get casted to integers when used for field names because field names in `awk` are numbers. The variable `host` contains a string which will get casted to `0`. This makes `awk` print `$0` twice.

---

Note that you can simplify this:

```
BEGIN { FS=":" }
NR%2==1 { host=$1 };
NR%2==0 { print host ":" $0 }
```

Comment: oh, ffs
Thank you!!

Comment: [being cheeky] it can also be written as `BEGIN {FS=":"}; NR%2 {printf "%s:", $1; next}; 1`